# Tranversing and filtering a Set comparing its objects' getters to an Array using Stream

Tags: for-loop, java-8, java-stream

I've got some working, inelegant code here:

The custom object is:

```
 public class Person {
    private int id;

    public getId() { return this.id }
}
```

And I have a Class containing a `Set<Person> allPersons` containing all available subjects. I want to extract a new `Set<Person>` based upon one or more ID's of my choosing. I've written something which works using a nested enhanced for loop, but it strikes me as inefficient and will make a lot of unnecessary comparisons. I am getting used to working with Java 8, but can't quite figure out how to compare the Set against an Array. Here is my working, but verbose code:

```
public class MyProgram {
    private Set<Person> allPersons; // contains 100 people with Ids 1-100

    public Set<Person> getPersonById(int[] ids) {
        Set<Person> personSet = new HashSet<>() //or any type of set
        for (int i : ids) {
            for (Person p : allPersons) {
                if (p.getId() == i) {
                    personSet.add(p);
                }
            }
        }
        return personSet;
    }
}
```

And to get my result, I'd call something along the lines of:

```
Set<Person> resultSet = getPersonById(int[] intArray = {2, 56, 66});
//resultSet would then contain 3 people with the corresponding ID
```

My question is how would i convert the getPersonById method to something using which streams allPersons and finds the ID match of any one of the ints in its parameter array? I thought of some filter operation, but since the parameter is an array, I can't get it to take just the one I want only.

---

The working answer to this is:

```
return allPersons.stream()
                 .filter(p -> (Arrays.stream(ids).anyMatch(i -> i == p.getId())) )
                 .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

However, using the bottom half of @Flown's suggestion and if the program was designed to have a Map - it would also work (and work much more efficiently)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, you can introduce a `Stream::filter` step using a `Stream::anyMatch` operation.

```
public Set<Person> getPersonById(int[] ids) {
  Objects.requireNonNull(ids);
  if (ids.length == 0) {
    return Collections.emptySet();
  }
  return allPersons.stream()
      .filter(p -> IntStream.of(ids).anyMatch(i -> i == p.getId()))
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

---

If the method is called more often, then it would be a good idea to map each `Person` to its `id` having a `Map<Integer, Person>`. The advantage is, that the lookup is much faster than iterating over the whole set of `Person`.

Then your algorithm may look like this:

```
private Map<Integer, Person> idMapping;

public Set<Person> getPersonById(int[] ids) {
  Objects.requireNonNull(ids);
  return IntStream.of(ids)
      .filter(idMapping::containsKey)
      .mapToObj(idMapping::get)
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Comment: That top answer definitely works with the code as is. I'd have to do a lot of reformatting to make the bottom work throughout the rest of the program at this point, but it's a good idea. Would there be a way to throw an IllegalArgumentException if one of the `ids` passed never matched with `p.getId()` ?

Comment: @NateH06: just remove the `.filter(idMapping::containsKey)`. Then, perform a single `if(resultSet.contains(null)) throw new IllegalArgumentException(…);` afterwards.

Comment: Ah, ok, so the `.mapToObj(idMapping::get)` is fine enough on its own? And it will just insert a null `Person` in to `resultSet` if the id is not a key of idMapping. 

And I'm actually seeing now with @Flown 's answer that  IntelliJ is telling me it cannot resolve the `IntStream` portion of their top answer. I've checked and as I have `java.util* imported`, it should work. I replaced the `IntStream` with `Arrays.stream(ids)` and it solved the issue. So my filter method looks like: `.filter(p -> (Arrays.stream(ids).anyMatch(i -> i == p.getId())) )`